# Count number of users who have permission to a folder python

Tags: python

Is it possible to count the number of users who have permission to a file with python ?

I have tried the os module with stat but I don’t know how to count the number of users who have permission to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for OS-specific information, I'm inclined to just suggest going straight to doing a shell command.

You can run something like this shell command in the python script.

```
namei -o README.md | awk '{print $2}' | tail +2 # lists the users. awk chooses the 2nd column and tail skips the first line.
```